# How can I set a min/max width to highchart's columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using 'Highcharts' column chart (not stacked).
My graph presents a dynamic data, so I don't know how many columns I'm expecting. That's why I would like to set a minimum and maximum width to the columns - when there are a lot of columns, I want as many columns as possible to be shown on my chart without needing a scroll (so the column's width is equal the min width); when there are only a few columns, I would like the columns to be in a reasonable width and not to spread all over the chart (the max width).
I know I can set the 'pointWidth' property, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.
If you have any idea, I will be more than thankful.

TIA,
adi

Comment: See [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968595/maximum-bar-width-in-highcharts-column-charts) questions. Actually my answer is including `maxPointWidth` but the same way you can implement `minPointWidth`. Or use point/groupPadding like in answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to not set the pointWidth and just let highcharts work it out for you. Use the pointPadding option to specify the gap between columns, and highcharts will do the rest.

e.g. this fiddle shows the same chart rendering different numbers of points: http://jsfiddle.net/122k2x5s/

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0.1,
            groupPadding: 0,
```